# Probability of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Hi have the following problem... I have a tank represented with a Gaussian random variable: $X\sim N(6;0.25)$, the request:

- Check that the sum of two independent measures is greater than 10 meters

How can I check my solution? Thank you

Comment: You should add your attempt with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The sum of two independent measures is still a Gaussian

$Z=X+Y \sim N(12; 0.5)$

Comment: thanks for your help... Now I can continue by Q function and find $P(Z>10)=Q(\frac{10-12}{0.70})$ right?

Comment: @BigBro : yes, but check you sdev: $\sqrt{0.5}\approx 0.71$

Comment: perfect... I quote your answer like the best. Thank you so much